# Verilog concatenation with 0 bit length

Tags: verilog

I'm defining an assign. In some configurations, one field will be 0 bits in length. E.g.

```
assign fullSig = {couldExist[`COULDEXIST_RNG],doesExist[`DOESEXIST_RNG]};
```

Is this allows if `` `COULDEXIST_RNG `` is set to `0:0`?

Comment: Note that [0:0] is not 0 bits in length.  That's 1 bit wide.  Index ranges are inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment you'll see that it's actually impossible to declare a zero length register or wire.  There is a way to dummy out an element of a concatination though.  Say you had `{a, b, c}`, if you wanted in some cases to not have `b` in there you could write `{a, {FLAG{b}}, c}` where `FLAG` is a parameter set to either 0 or 1.  A zero repetition concatenation is treated as having zero length.  `b` will still have to be declared somewhere however.